# Facebook iFrame App to Fit Facebook Canvas in iPad

Tags: facebook, ipad, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

Note the following issue been solved by update iOS to the latest version (9.0.2)

---

I have a web application, that runs in Facebook as iFrame.
It worked perfect for long time, and still working in my PC, but now in iPad, they make the facebook canvas smaller and somehow my app is NOT fit the new Facebook canvas size.
How I can make the app fit the size of Facebook canvas size?

I see in the app setting:

> Canvas Fixed Width "Yes" sets canvas width to 760 px"
>   But this is for sure FB bug, because FB iPad canvas width is much smaller than 760px in their last iPad app.
>   Also there is no way to define custom width .

Comment: Don’t set the width to fixed …?

Comment: Well if you have it set to flexible width, then your app must be able to handle basically whatever width it gets. If responsive web design techniques are completely new to you, then start researching those.

Comment: My app work on any page size, something in the iPad canvas seems not the same as prev version (which my app worked well)

Comment: _“My app work on any page size”_ – if that was the case, then what are you asking about here?

Comment: Seems like the canvas size when the page loaded is bigger than the actual frame (the frame where the iframe app display). It seems like the fact the width in setting is 760 px, while i see in the last version of the iPad is for sure have frame less than 640px mean FB have a bug !!!!

Comment: Well if you think there’s a bug, then report it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ But make sure to provide a proper example and explanation of what is needed to reproduce this, and why you think this is a bug on their end (and not something you have messed up yourself, which I for one am not convinced of yet – but that might be due to your rather lacking problem description.)

Comment: @CBroe seems like you have too much time!!! , I do not need your sarcasm.

Comment: That wasn’t sarcasm, but just a hint that if you file a bug report, it should have actual substance to it (which your question here doesn’t), so as to not waste FB developer’s time looking into it.

Comment: @CBroe I asked here to see if someone deal with the same issue, because I couldn't find anything in my code. Anyway thanks for your time and support, I find that after I update my iOS version everything works perfect (why exactly the new version solve the issue?! I have no idea). maybe Facebook developers forum should be my place to post this question. Enjoy your weekend!

Answer (score 0):

update iOS to the latest one (9.0.2) solve the issue!